# Installation type screen freezes 18.04

Tags: freeze

The installer always freezes on the Installation type screen. The page loads with an empty partition table and "new partition table" is disabled.

If I click "Install Now", I am left with the error message that a root has not been set.
If I click +, the program freezes and the computer must be restarted.
- shows the same message as install now, but I am allowed to proceed with the installation but with many warning messages.
The installation inevitably fails.
Any other button also leads to the freeze or failure.

[image]